# What's a good way to draw multiple circles?

Tags: unity

Why does the following code not work?

```
public float ThetaScale = 0.0001f;
private int Size;
private LineRenderer LineDrawer;
private float Theta = 0f;

void Start ()
 {
  LineDrawer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  LineDrawer.SetWidth(0.1f, 0.1f);
  LineDrawer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Mobile/Particles/Additive"));
  LineDrawer.SetColors(Color.blue, Color.blue);
 }


void DrawingCircle(float radius)
{
Theta = 0f;
Size = (int)((1f / ThetaScale) + 1f);
LineDrawer.SetVertexCount(Size);
for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
    Theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * ThetaScale);
    float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(Theta);
    float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(Theta);
    LineDrawer.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, y, 0));
}}


void Update ()
{
    for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
    {
        DrawingCircle(l);
    }
 }
```

I want to plot a multiple circles like that

[image]

What's a good way to draw multiple circles?

Comment: What does your current code do, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: A LineRenderer is a component like any other. You don't need to update it every frame even when nothing changed.

Comment: Note also that you are using one render for all three circles but you are overwriting the previous circle each time so you will only ever see the last circle

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion comes from a misunderstanding of what [the LineRenderer component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) does.

A LineRenderer isn't a "line drawer". It doesn't draw lines. It visualizes a game object in form of a visible polygon strip in 3d space. Just like a SpriteRenderer visualizes a game object as a sprite or a MeshRenderer visualizes a game object as a 3d mesh.

So when you want 3 separate lines in your game, you need 3 different game objects with a LineRenderer each. When their coordinates don't change, you only need to set them once. It's not necessary to reassign their components in every update.

Comment: I think you could get away with one GameObject with three line renderer components attached to it.